# how Do I parse string and convert it into date and finally into epoch time?

Tags: java, date, localdate, date-parsing

I want to convert a string to date and get epochtime from that date. following is my code which is giving me error

```
       DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-mm-dd");

       LocalDateTime localDate = LocalDateTime.parse(day, formatter);

       long TCepochtime = localDate.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(19800));
```

it gives me error at line 2

day string is "2019-12-25"

Comment: It looks like you are trying to parse a date in a LocalDateTime, I suggest you use the LocalDate instead as well as using the DateFormatter instead of the DateTimeFormatter.

Comment: Also I think your pattern formatting is incorrect, it is case sensitive, so it might need to be "yyyy-MM-dd", alternatively  you could try using the ISO_LOCAL_DATE constant

Comment: It’s a bit simpler than you thought. `LocalDate.parse("2019-12-25").atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Asia/Colombo")).toEpochSecond()` yields 1577212200. Insert your desired time zone. Don’t use `ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds()` for a time zone, it’s unreadable and will give a wrong result when used with historic dates or once the politicians change the offset for your time zone.